# What's the correct place to put a properties file for a TeamCity plugin so that it could be easy editable?

Tags: java, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I am writing a TeamCity plugin and I'm trying to figure out what the best place to put a `.properties` file would be. I was under the impression that the `data/config` dir would be on the `CLASSPATH`, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Could somebody please give me some examples of existing plugins which are configurable via a `.properties` file on the file system and how this all should work?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a `@NotNull ServerPaths serverPaths` (see [Javadoc](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/8.1/jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/ServerPaths.html#getConfigDir())) as a parameter to your constructor. Then you can do:

```
File propertiesFile = new File(serverPaths.getConfigDir() + "/my-plugin.properties");
```

... and then load up the properties file using a `FileInputStream`.